# Hide png image until its displayed within users screen

Tags: html, css, css-animations

At the moment I have a css animation that starts off screen (as below) and travels to the right. (see here http://crea8tion.com/ChristmasMessage/index.html)

I've noticed during testing that on some screens it's still showing on the left of the screen before the animation starts.

Is there something additional I can do that hides the png based on the user's screen size?

Here is what I have at the moment, you can see it's simply offset to the left.

```
.santa {
    width: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -14%;
    left: -75%;
    -webkit-animation: santa-move 1s 1s ease-out forwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay:5s;animation-delay:5s;                   
    -webkit-animation-duration: 25s;

    -moz-animation: santa-move 1s 1s ease-out forwards;
    -moz-animation-delay:5s;animation-delay:5s;                   
    -moz-animation-duration: 25s;
}
```

Comment: Please DO NOT link to your web site. Here's why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: use `visibility:hidden` then change it to `visible` when you want to show it

Comment: But when I want to show it would be depending on when the user sees it appear on their screen and thats dependent on their screen size. How does this resolve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the dimensions of the object itself to hide things just offscreen. The left value should be the negation of the width, in this case `left:-100px`

```
.santa {
    left:-1000px;
    top:-200px; /* However tall santa is */
    ...
}
```